# Is it possible to unicast firebase realtime db responses

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my android app, I have two scenarios

First scenario : Response from firebase realtime db to be sent to all the clients( was able to achieve)

Second scenario : Response from firebase realtime db needs to be sent only to the client who queries.

Could you suggest me how to achieve the second scenario.

Comment: Can give provides us a concrete example?

Comment: In my app, there is a questionnaire section where user will be posting a question into the firebase realtime db and I have a cloud function which analyse that question and post an answer into the db , and that answer needs to be unicast only to that user.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Database synchronizes state between the server and all clients. It is explicitly not designed as a message-passing server.

You can easily build a message passing service on top of the database, by storing the messages for each user you want to deliver them to. A simple structure for that could be:

```
Inboxes
  uidOfPeppy
    message1: {...}
    message3: {...}
  uidOfPuf
    message2: {...}
```

With this structure you write the message to the "inbox" of each user you want to have access to it.

Comment: Thanks Frank, Could you share me the code snippet or tutorial to get more details about your suggested implementation, Sorry because I am pretty new with this stuff.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not how Stack Overflow works. If you are not ready to implement this approach, I recommend starting with the [Android codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/) to get a quick intro into the API.